# How do I download a file from a Byte[] array in a Web Api2 method that returns IHttpActionResult?

Tags: download, asp.net-web-api2

Below is the method I've got in my ApiController class.
The _fileContents dictionary is populated in another WebApi2 method BuildContent(params).
When the user makes an ajax call to the BuildContent(params) method, the method builds
the string end of the dictionary, which contains full HTML content including a table tag and passes back a the Guid, end of the dictionary. The javascript in turn does the following:

```
window.location = 'api/MyController/DownloadFile/' + guid;
```

ApiController static:

```
private static Dictionary<Guid, String> _fileContents = new Dictionary<Guid, String>();
```

ApiController method:

```
public IHttpActionResult DownloadFile(Guid guid)
{
   try
    {
      if (_fileContents.ContainsKey(guid))
      {
         HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
         var content = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_fileContents[guid]);
         using (var stream = new MemoryStream(content))
         {
            result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
                      new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
                           new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "MyFile.bin";
         }
       return Ok(result);
      }
      else
      {
        return NotFound();
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     return InternalServerError(ex);
   }

    return BadRequest();
}
```

The calling sequence works perfectly but the DownloadFile() method throws the following exception:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type             'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type 'System.Net.Http.StreamContent' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the     DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with     the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with     the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for         other supported types.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException
</ExceptionType>
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on and how to accomplish my goal of downloading a simple html file?

Comment: Did you solve this? Just ran into the same problem.